# Help translating instructions since English website has been shut down

Tags: translation

Can someone help me in translating these instructions. The English website has been shut down.  I'm trying to find out how to do a hard reset on this device.

The products English website was [Onn-w7 website](http://en.onnchina.com/mp3_mp4/product172.html)

[image: Page 1]

[image: Page 2]

Comment: Time for an upgrade may be?  M3P players are basically obsolete nowadays. Anyone have a smart phone can play MP3 with it. A brand new MP3 player would not costs more than $50.

Comment: @TangHo  True, but the old mp3 players don't have issues with Modulated Tesla coils.  If you try and use a good modulated Tesla coil and a cell phone or a tablet at the same time the cell phone / tablet will behave erratic and may reboot due to the high frequency the Tesla coils produce `the old mp3 players don't have these issues`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options:

1. Press the power button for more than three seconds. This is what instruction says: `电源开关长按3秒以上开机`.
2. According to [this](https://youtu.be/0Rzs_MSKSS4?t=303) Belorussian guy, you can take a needle and press the reset button inside the [round hole near the SD card slot](https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1X_8nHpXXXXbhXFXXq6xXFXXXp/206306760/HTB1X_8nHpXXXXbhXFXXq6xXFXXXp.jpg?size=53837&height=790&width=790&hash=fe3f864fb8512fa791ca82bdfde5722c). (This method is not on the manual.)

These methods might not do an actual hardware reset, though. No guarantees here.